# how to make Image.Save save as a 24-bit image?

Tags: c#, gdi+

How do I get C# to force bitmap images that are saved to be saved as 24-bit images as can be seen when you get the right-click properties of the image in Windows.  All the images I save are set to 32-bit.
I tried the below code with no luck.  The source images are all 24-bit as well but are always saved as 32-bit images.

```
ImageCodecInfo bmpCodec = FindEncoder(ImageFormat.Bmp);
EncoderParameters parameters = new EncoderParameters();
parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.ColorDepth, 24);
imgCheque.Save(DestinationFile.ToString(), bmpCodec, parameters);
```

The images have to be properly 24 bit as the are read by a different program that can't handle 32-bit images.

Thanks in advance,

Soultech

Comment: I think there's something wrong in the code posted... double-check `bmpCode` vs `jpegCodec`

Comment: yeah sorry, it is bitmaps I am try to create.  I have amended it now. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Is this any use?

```
// imgCheque source created somewhere else up here
using (Bitmap blankImage = new Bitmap(imgCheque.Width, imgCheque.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
{
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(blankImage))
    {
        g.DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped(imgCheque, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, imgCheque.Size));
    }

    ImageCodecInfo bmpCodec = FindEncoder(ImageFormat.Bmp);
    blankImage.Save(@"C:\TEMP\output.bmp", bmpCodec, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
ImageCodecInfo bmpCodec = FindEncoder(ImageFormat.Bmp);
EncoderParameters parameters = new EncoderParameters();
parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.ColorDepth, 24L);
imgCheque.Save(DestinationFile.ToString(), bmpCodec, parameters);
```